I'm facing Forest error during rebalancing
While running rebalancing I'm getting Forrest error but database available. Please refer the below error. Can I restart the forest to resolve this error?
We are configured Automatic cache setting.

There is currently an exception: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in rebalance of forest Forest-1: XDMP-REBALANCE: Error rebalancing fn:doc("/XYZ6.xml"): XDMP-FRAGTOOLARGE: Fragment of /XYZ6.xml too large for in-memory storage: XDMP-INMMTRPLFULL: In-memory triple storage full; list: table=4%, wordsused=2%, wordsfree=96%, overhead=1%; tree: table=0%, wordsused=1%, wordsfree=99%, overhead=0%


XDMP-FRAGTOOLARGE means that you are bumping against configured limits for maximum size of a document.
How big is the document, and what sort of content does it hold?
You could try increasing limits to allow for this large document to be loaded.
From the message you posted, it appears that you are hitting the in-memory triple index limit:

XDMP-INMMTRPLFULL: In-memory triple storage full

So, you could look at increasing the database In Memory Triple Index Size. Refer to:
Understanding XDMP-INMM*FULL messages
Generally, when really, really large docs are being loaded - it is often better to break them up and load many smaller docs (think, loading rows of a table as documents instead of storing the entire table as one big document). But maybe in this case, you just happen to have a bunch of triples and that is necessary for your use-case. It's difficult to know without knowing anything about your content and use cases.
There are times when you really do want/need such large docs as a single item. So, you can look at increasing the in-memory limits to make room for them, or if you don't need all of the indexing and capabilities to exploit - and simply PUT and GET, then you can bypass all of that overhead by storing the document as a binary-node(), so that it doesn't try to tokenize words/terms and track positions of JSON properties, XML elements/attributes, triples, etc.
